# How does Buffer overcome Twitter API limits?

Tags: twitter

Buffer claims to have millions of users, all scheduling posts. The free plan allows for 10 posts per day.

How does Buffer overcome Twitter API limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not bypassing the limit, they're doing the queries on your behalf. I don't have an account with them, but most sites where you can login to them using Twitter utilize your credentials to submit the queries allowing them to do many at once.

A good way to test this is going to your profile settings, then click on either `Apps` or `Your Twitter Data` you should see their name popup there. For their paid version, they could purchase an increase in limit from Twitter but you'll end up paying for that through their pricing cost.